# Both displays crash if I change any display settings

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have a secondary display set up on my Laptop which works fine with the default settings (secondary display on the right of primary).  However if I change any settings both screens go black.  This includes changing the relative positions, using keyboard hotkeys to turn off the primary monitor, or just about anything else.

My specs are the following:

- Lenovo X1 Carbon

  - Intel Core i5
  - Intel Ivybridge Mobile
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (I must use this version for work)
- Display connected via Mini-DP <--> Apple-branded VGA converter <--> monitor

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue when I use a mini-DP to Displayport adapter instead.  I'm just going to use that solution instead.